Understanding the meaning of simple tenses with conjunctions
I'd like to ask if I'm right that using present or past simple with conjunctions may be sometimes ambiguous.

When I came in she cooked

Here,everything is clear "come" is a short activity therefore everyone knows that cooking happend after "coming". If one is eager to emphasize that one can say " When I had come" but there is no need for that. The original version is clear on its own

When I jumped she jumped

This one is quite ambiguous. It can mean something like that "when I was jumping she was jumping" so two events happening at the same time. Another possibility is "when I was jumping she jumped" so a short action disrupting a longer one or "when I had jumped she jumped" meaning my jump made her jump after not at the same time. Are my 3 ways of understanding correct? Am I right that the meaning may be ambiguous?

These are not billboard signs. There is usually context. "When I jumped, she jumped." "You mean at the same time every time? Or each time you jumped, she then also jumped?" People ask to clarify.

@YosefBaskin Thank you. Please, answer my additional questions too. 1) For my 2 example I provided 3 meanings. I don't think the second one with a disrupting event is a possible meaning, do you? 2) "When I cooked she played" in my original example " jump" is a short event. As I understand with long actions such as "cooking" the meaning may also be ambiguous whether at the same time or one after another?


"When I arrive she works" Am I right that here the meaning is clear bacuase arrive is a short activity indicating that working happens one i have arrived?


Are your old user accounts named Gregor and Adam? 1. Present continuous and conditionals 2. Time clauses reported speech

also related: "When I was playing she was cooking" and "she had been cooking" and I was cooking while she screamed

To pursue a little further the comment Kate Bunting made,  native speakers wouldn't say:

When I came in she cooked.

We might say:

When I came in she was cooking.
When I came in she began cooking.
When I came in she started to cook.
When I came in she cooked dinner.

She cooked  doesn't express any clear time-aspect. "she was cooking" says she was already cooking, had started cooking before I came in.  "she began cooking"and "she started to cook" both express the idea that her cooking commenced when I got in the door.   "she cooked dinner" implies that the discrete action of her cooking dinner followed upon my arrival.   Because of the direct object, "she cooked dinner"  is rooted in time, a discrete action, whereas "she cooked" is temporally indefinite.

"When I came in she cooked dinner." Here we have one short event "come" and one that is long "cook" because of that the meaning is rather clear "when I had come in she cooked dinner" they are not events happening at the same time. Check this example "When I played she danced" here I am pretty sure the meaning isn"t that clear because it is either two events happening at the same time or one happnes after another and we need context to know, correct?

"cooked" is not a "long" action.  It is atelic.  "Cooked dinner" is telic if it is understood to mean "made the evening meal".  It has a clear goal or result. "When I played she danced"  -- "played" is not the same as "came in".  It doesn't establish a point-in-time.

Consider: "When I began playing she stood up and danced.".

people told me that this "When I jumped she jumped" means either  "When I was jumping, she was jumping" or "When I jumped once, she jumped once." Does my example "When I played she danced' work the same and why?

@user203412  When I jumped can mean "When I made a single leap on a particular occasion, as over a puddle" or "When I was startled by the scary movie" (similar aspectually) or "Back when I was parachuting" (very different aspectually) and the meaning should be the same according the parallelism: When I jumped, she jumped.  That is "When I was startled by the scary movie, so was she" or "When I was parachuting on weekends, so was she."

If you mean to say that she danced to your playing on a particular occasion: "She danced while I played" or "While I played, she danced".  If you mean to say that you were a performing duo and this happened many times you could also say "While I played, she danced." for that scenario as well.   It is not a fruitful exercise when we begin without context, a barebones sentence, and describe what that barebones sentence might mean.  It does not mean that your playing initiated her dancing.

As is noted in the comments, context means everything here. You're right that the second sentence is ambiguous, and you've given examples of possible meanings. But that's true of the first sentence as well. For example:

My wife was very loyal to me. For years, every night when I came in from work, she cooked a meal for me.

Now it's still possible to read this as she didn't start cooking until after I got home. But it's also possible to imagine this as when I got home a meal was ready for me. The two actions are scheduled to happen at the same time.
Note that if this is right, what makes it right is the additional context.
For me the important part of all these sentences is when. If I read this word my first instinct is to assume that the related actions are happening at the same time, and I only adjust that assumption if there are further clues in the narrative.

Thank you. Please, answer my additional questions too. 1) For my 2  example I provided 3 meanings. I don't think the second one with a disrupting event is a possible meaning, do you? 2) "When I cooked she played" in my original example " jump" is  a short event. As I understand with long actions such as "cooking" the meaning may also be ambiguous whether at the same time or one after another?


"When I arrive she works" Am I right that here the meaning is clear bacuase arrive is a short activity indicating that working happens one i have arrived?


I see that you posted the same comment to both answers. I've replied to these comments below the other answer.

Depending on the intended meaning, we would say "When I came in, she was cooking" (she had already started) OR "When I came in, she started to cook".

@KateBunting Could you answer my three questions which I provided in the comments. It will help me a lot.

To me, the most likely meaning of (2) would be that they both jumped (once) at the same time. Your second question isn't clear, but we would normally use the continuous tense for a 'long action'. (3) - The meaning is not clear. My comment about When I came in she cooked applies to this one too - is she already working, or does she start when you arrive?

@KateBunting I'm sorry. I will try to make my questions more vivid. A) "When I jumped she jumped" here I think that jumping either happens at the same time or one jump triggers another one so sequnce, without additional context we can't be sure. I gave one more option of how to understand this sentence that one event was longer and disturped  another one so " when I was jumping she jumped. To sum up only my two first interpretations make sense and are both equally possible and no one would interpet my original sentence the third way, correct?

B)"When I played she danced" Am I right that the same applies to this sentence so either actions happen at the same time or after playing dancing happens. Without context we can't be sure which interpreation is for sure right even though to me it rather means two events happen at the same time yet sequnce is possible too, correct?

The way native speakers would understand your sentences depends partly on your choice of verbs and the scenarios they suggest. I imagine two swimmers standing on the edge of a pool - when one jumps in, the other does so at the same time or immediately after. If you wanted to stress that one jump happened after the other, you would have to say "When I had jumped, she jumped [too]."

It's natural to assume that playing (music) accompanies dancing. In the same way, if her dance followed your musical solo, say "When/after I had played, she danced".

@KateBunting Yet, both interpretations are possible and context matters, right? "When we took our exam we made a party" here yet again both interpretations are possible at the same time or one after another but when it comes to this example common sense suggests that party happened once the action of taking exams was done, correct?

Yes, but in real life people would say "When we'd taken all our exams/when our exams were over, we had a party".

"When I jumped she jumped"
Am I right that the meaning may be ambiguous?
Context plays a part in deciding ambiguity. Without any context, this either means
"When I was jumping, she was jumping"
or
"When I jumped once, she jumped once."

There are at least 3 clearly-distinguishable meanings, since another one is "over many consecutive repetitions our jumps were synchronized" (as opposed to your first meaning, where "when" could be replaced by "while / whilst"). There may be other more contrived but context-determined distinctive meanings, I dunno.

@chasly --supports Monica  Thank you. Please, answer my additional questions too. 1) For my 2 example I provided 3 meanings. I don't think the second one with a disrupting event is a possible meaning, do you? 2) "When I cooked she played" in my original example " jump" is a short event. As I understand with long actions such as "cooking" the meaning may also be ambiguous whether at the same time or one after another?


"When I arrive she works" Am I right that here the meaning is clear bacuase arrive is a short activity indicating that working happens one i have arrived?


You keep talking about a short activity. Why? In your OP jumping is also a short activity. But you interpreted your two examples differently. I think you should forget about long or short activities. I think it's just confusing you.

When I arrive she works. I would understand this as something happening regularly. When = whenever, and the idea is "She doesn't work much, but whenever I arrive she starts working". Is that what you meant?

@PeterKirkpatrick That's what I meant but could you givr answers to my three questions. it would really help me thanks

I think the best thing you can do is not try to understand the different possible meanings of an ambiguous sentence. Instead, learn how to add context to communicate the actual meaning you have in mind. @TimR's answer is a good example of how to do that.
